# Doctrine Module objectSelect setvalue not working

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a simple question regarding Doctrine Modules Object Select.

I have a simple objectSelect form element

```
       $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'timezone',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => _('Timezone:'),
                'label_attributes' => array('class' => 'required'),
                'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
                'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\Timezones',
                'property' => 'timezone',
                'is_method' => true,
                'find_method' => array(
                    'name' => 'FindAll',
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

Now I want to select a certain option as default, I have used the setValue method to do this but it is not working.

```
$this->get('timezone')->setValue(335);
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any timezone with id 335?

Comment: Yes there is, is in in the options list of the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't working.

In my controller I was binding my form to a Doctrine entity which was empty.  This was overriding my values I set.  I added the values in my controller after the form was bound and this fixed the issue.

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
$site = new Sites($this->getServiceLocator());
$form = new AddSiteForm($this->getServiceLocator());
$form->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($entityManager));
$form->bind($site);
$form->get('timezone')->setValue(335);
$form->get('currencyCode')->setValue('GBP');
```